# Smooth vectors of unitary representations and reducibility

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory

A representation $(\pi,V)$ of a locally compact group $G$ is unitary if $V$ is a Hilbert space endowed with a $G-$invariant bilinear form. In general, a unitary representation can't be expressed as a direct sum of sub-representations (for example $L^2(\mathbb{R})$).

A smooth representation $(\sigma,W)$ of $G$ is pre-unitary if there exists a $G-$invariant bilinear form on $W$. Pre-unitary representations are known to be isomorphic to the direct sum of pre-unitary representations.

Let us assume that the smooth vectors of $(\pi,V)$ are equal to $(\sigma,W)$. If $(\pi,V)$ is reducible (there exists a sub-representation), then $(\sigma,W)$ is reducible? The other direction is true? If $(\pi,V) = \int^{\oplus}_{\hat{G}}\widehat{\bigoplus}^{m(\rho)}V_{\rho}d\mu(\rho)$, then $(\sigma, W) = \bigoplus_{\rho\in \hat{G}}^{m(\rho)}V_{\rho}^{\infty}$?